# Explanation for problem of choosing at least two elements from array such that their GCD is 1 and cost is minimum

Tags: c++, dictionary

While reading the solution to the problem [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/choose-atleast-two-elements-from-array-such-that-their-gcd-is-1-and-cost-is-minimum/?fbclid=IwAR1yLnavqOyh6R6G59dZ7QkGdJ5V4ys9cCwTFd5w8XKzxLkYCLwfTqLNXjg), I noticed that during the iteration through the map (second for), in some cases some insertions are performed in the same map (the 'else'). What is the behavior of the for loop in this case? Is the new insertion omitted by the iteration? Is this correct?

Edit: here is the code

```
// C++ implementation of the approach 

#include <bits/stdc++.h> 

using namespace std; 

  

// Function to return the minimum cost required 

int getMinCost(int arr[], int n, int cost[]) 

{ 

  

    // Map to store <gcd, cost> pair where 

    // cost is the cost to get the current gcd 

    map<int, int> mp; 

    mp.clear(); 

    mp[0] = 0; 

  

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 

        for (auto it : mp) { 

            int gcd = __gcd(arr[i], it.first); 

  

            // If current gcd value already exists in map 

            if (mp.count(gcd) == 1) 

  

                // Update the minimum cost 

                // to get the current gcd 

                mp[gcd] = min(mp[gcd], it.second + cost[i]); 

  

            else

                mp[gcd] = it.second + cost[i]; 

        } 

    } 

  

    // If there can be no sub-set such that 

    // the gcd of all the elements is 1 

    if (mp[1] == 0) 

        return -1; 

    else

        return mp[1]; 

}
```

Comment: All those blank lines make for a whole lot of scrolling, too, so try and trim those out as well. Being able to see all the code at a glance can help identify problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to your question: does the insertion leave the iterator used in the for loop as a valid iterator, and if so is the newly inserted element earlier in the map or later?

Inserting into a map (via [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) does not invalidate iterators, so the compiler generated iterator for that second for loop is still valid after a new element is added.

Because the Greatest Common Divisor is always less or equal to the two numbers, the newly inserted element will have a lower value that `it.first` (since an equal value will not add a new element). Because a `std::map` is a sorted container (typically stored as a binary tree), iterating thru a `std::map` will start with the lowest element and work to the largest. Since the new element is less than the current element in the for loop, the new element will not be processed by the current loop (although it will be for the next iteration of the outer `i` loop).

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't think about the gcd being lower than the elements. It makes sense now.